# tree command for multiple includes and excludes

Tags: tree, options

Could you please give me an example of using the tree command to filter out result as follows:

- to ignore directories (say `bin`, `unitTest`)
- only listing certain files having extensions (say `.cpp`, `.c`, `.hpp`, `.h`)
- providing full path-names of only the resultant files matching the criteria.

Answer (score 86):

One way is to use patterns with the `-I` and `-P` switches:

```
tree -f -I "bin|unitTest" -P "*.[ch]|*.[ch]pp." your_dir/
```

The `-f` prints the full path for each file, and `-I` excludes the files in the pattern here separated by a vertical bar. The `-P` switch inlcudes only the files listed in the pattern matching a certain extension.

Comment: *Note: do not include trailing slashes in your -I flag, eg `-I bin`, not `-I bin/`.*

Comment: this makes an error `sed: illegal option -- I`

Answer (score 4):

use `find` and `tree` command that is use find's `prune` to exclude directories of search and use `tree -P` for searching the pattern.

Use the prune switch, for example if you want to exclude the `misc` directory just add a `-path ./misc -prune -o`to your find command.

for eg.`find . -path ./misc -prune -o -exec tree -P <pattern> {} \;` or you can use `-name "*.cpp" in find`

for excluding multiple directories use

`find . -type d \( -path dir1 -o -path dir2 -o -path dir3 \) -prune -o`

Comment: For me, example with find gives error "find: expected an expression after '-o'
"

Comment: did you try just `find . -type d \( -path dir1 -o -path dir2 -o -path dir3 \) -prune -o` or `find . -path ./misc -prune -o -exec tree -P *.cpp {} \;`

Answer (score 4):

The true solution is to output full paths, filter unwanted paths out, and finally fix the outputs.

```
tree -df | egrep -v "\./(bin|unitTest)/.*" | sed -r 's%\./.*/%%g'
```

If all files are necessary in the output, remove the "d" parameter.

Detailed explanation can be found at: http://qaon.net/press/archives/572 if you can understand Japanese.

Comment: -f flag super useful!

Comment: To get the same format as `tree` without arguments, use: `sed -r 's%\..*/%%g'`.  After that, the only difference is the loss of colored output.

Answer (score 0):

Use awk:

```
tree -f | awk ‘!/bin|unitTest/ && /\.cpp|\.c|\.hpp|\.h/ {print}’
```

The first pattern is your excludes and the second is your includes.